# Unable to upload/convert videos using Paperclip-FFMPEG gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ffmpeg, paperclip

**FIXED:** It's due to a typo in the relevant lib file that I hadn't spotted! See [this issue](https://github.com/owahab/paperclip-ffmpeg/issues/6) for more details.

---

I'm still a bit of a Ruby on Rails newbie (running Rails 3.2.6 and Ruby 1.9.3p194), but I'm finding it very difficult to convert video files using the paperclip-ffmpeg gem. No matter what I do, an error message is displayed on the page after attempting to upload the video:

**"cannot load such file: /[...My info...]/lib/paperclip_processors/ffmpeg.rb"**

I'm trying to test using .mov files for the moment.

I'm trying to follow the [instructions on the gem's github page](https://github.com/owahab/paperclip-ffmpeg), but without much success.

Firstly, I'm using a Mac (Snow Leopard) and ffmpeg is installed (running `which ffmpeg` tells me it's in `/user/local/bin/ffmpeg`)

In my application, I've added the following lines to the gemfile:

```
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'paperclip-ffmpeg'
```

I've also added `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"` to config/environments/development.rb as per the instructions:

```
Myapp::Application.configure do

...

Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
end
```

(The instructions also suggest "in your environment config file, let Paperclip know to look there by adding that directory to its path", but I don't know what this means - maybe this is the problem?).

My class is structured as follows:

```
class Myvideo > ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :description, :title, :video

  has_attached_file :video, :styles => { 
      :medium => { :geometry => "640x480", :format => 'flv' }
    }, :processors => [:ffmpeg]


end
```

My understanding is that the above code converts the uploaded movie from .mov (or whatever) to .flv format.

However, the error I describe above appears whenever the user clicks on the Upload button (save for a few seconds while the video appears to be uploading).

Note that I can upload a video via the standard Paperclip gem *without* converting with no problems. Therefore, this code works (i.e. the video is uploaded but no conversion occurs):

```
attr_accessible :description, :title, :video

  has_attached_file :video
```

Any ideas where I might be going wrong? Thanks!

---

EDIT - the original error message ("Cannot load such file...") appears to have arisen because I hadn't included the relevant ffmpeg.rb file from Github within the `/lib` directory. Thanks to @wehal3001 for pointing this out!

However, while I now have this file in my application, I still get the following error when trying to upload a video:

**uninitialized constant Paperclip::Ffmpeg::PaperclipError
...
lib/paperclip_processors/ffmpeg.rb:123:in `rescue in make'
lib/paperclip_processors/ffmpeg.rb:120:in`make'
app/controllers/videos_controller.rb:43:in `new'
app/controllers/videos_controller.rb:43:in`create'**

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: does the file `/[...My info...]/lib/paperclip_processors/ffmpeg.rb` exist? it appears Paperclip can not find the ffmpeg processor file.

Comment: Actually, you're right, the folder is not there! Unusual - shouldn't the folder and relevant files be created when the gem is installed (or am I missing something due to my inexperience)? I tried copying and pasting the code from the relevant lib file in the github repository, but now I get the following error: ** uninitialized constant Paperclip::Ffmpeg::PaperclipError **

Comment: GOT IT!!! It was a typo (not mine ;-) ) in the relevant ffmpeg.rb file. See [this issue](https://github.com/owahab/paperclip-ffmpeg/issues/6) for details. As this might catch out other devs, I'll leave the issue up here for now.